# Sidekiq generating worker specific queues

Tags: queue, sidekiq

I have 2 workers that I want to run in the same queue

```
class ReportWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :queue => :metrics
  #....
end

class ObjectiveWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :queue => :metrics
  #....
end
```

I have a sidekiq priority extension setup so Objective worker runs before Priority Worker

```
ObjectiveWorker.perform_with_priority(:objective, oid)
```

but the workers are being generated in their own unique queues - `metrics_objective` and `metrics_report`

What am I doing wrong?